# PHP Image Gallery without javascript

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, photo-gallery

I am looking for a simple PHP gallery with the following characteristics:

- Pure PHP
- HTML
- CSS
- SQL
- Excludes JavaScript
- Handle Subcategories
- Easily customizable

I have tried to search, but I find only with JavaScript or Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a mysql database to store the location of the images on your ftp server. then use php to get the rows of the database and echo them out using a while statement.

you can either look into it further.

Comment: finally i use this solution, because the already written galleries is not customizable as i want.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to PHPAlbum, which make no use of anything except PHP (comes with an installer or the regular files to upload yourself)

[phpAlbum website](http://www.phpalbum.net/)  there is also a [demo site](http://www.phpalbum.net/demo4/main.php?cmd=album)

Now if you're not completely against tiny bits of JS you have this tutorial ([link](http://www.lateralcode.com/create-a-simple-picture-gallery-using-php/)) to create a simple pics gallery with PHP, but effects around pics are added from the loaded JS lib (which you can avoid and use the PHP code only)
Have fun